# If $W$ is a subspace of $V$ and if $\{g_1,\ldots,g_r\}$ basis of $W^0,$ then $W= \bigcap\limits_{i=1}^{r} N_{g_i}.$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I am trying to solve Problem No $2$ in exercise $3.6$ from the linear algebra book by Hoffman Kunze. Problem is the following.

> If $W$ is a subspace of a finite dimensional vector space $V$ and if $\{g_1,\ldots,g_r\}$ is any basis of $W^0,$ then $W= \bigcap\limits_{i=1}^{r} N_{g_i}.$

We know that $W^0= \{f : V \to \mathbb{F} : f(W)=0\}$ and also know that $\rm dim(W)+ \rm dim (W^0)= \rm dim(V).$

Some hints are also given as following : If $g,f_1,\ldots,f_r$ be linear functionals on a vector space $V$ with respective null spaces $N,N_1,\ldots,N_r.$ Then $g$ is a linear combination of $f_1,\ldots,f_r$ iff $N$ contains the intersection $N_1\cap\cdots\cap N_r$.

I couldn't prove this  way $\bigcap\limits_{i=1}^{r} N_{g_i} \subset W$ while the other way is trivial.
I need some help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As
$$\bigcap\limits_{i=1}^{r} N_{g_i} \subset W\iff \bigcap\limits_{i=1}^r N_{g_i}\setminus W= \emptyset,$$
suppose that there is $x_0\in\bigcap\limits_{i=1}^r N_{g_i}\setminus W$. Now, as $x_0\in\bigcap\limits_{i=1}^r N_{g_i}$ means $g_i(x_0) = 0$ for all $i$, and $\{g_1,\ldots,g_r\}$ is a basis of $W^0$, we have $f(x_0) = 0$ for all $f\in W^0$.

But if $x_0\not\in W$, then there exists some $f_0$ s.t. $f_0(x_0)\ne 0$ and $f_0|_W = 0$ (why?). The second condition means that $f_0\in W^0$. Contradiction.

Comment: How can I get such a $f$ with $f(x) \ne 0$ and $x \in \bigcap\limits_{i=1}^r N_{g_i} $  also $  \bigcap\limits_{i=1}^r N_{g_i} \subset N_f$ ?

Comment: @user371231, take $\{x\}\cup$ (a basis of the intersection) $\cup$ (the vectors required to complete a basis of the space).

Comment: @ Martín-Blas Pérez Pinilla,  My question is how is it possible ? since $x$ is  already in the intersection by your choice of $x$ !

Comment: @user371231, it is "possible" because  $f$ can be defined by the values that takes in a basis. But by the intermediate result, it is impossible. Contradiction!

Comment: @user371231, proving the intermediate result is required also?

Comment: @ Martín-Blas Pérez Pinilla ,Sir you need not to prove any result just give me a proper order of arguments ... I am not understanding.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54732/discussion-between-user371231-and-martin-blas-perez-pinilla).

Comment: @user371231, my first comment was wrong: the correct idea is take $\{x\}\cup $ (a basis of $W$) $\cup$ (the vectors required to complete a basis of the space).

Answer (score 0):

We can make use of the hint in the following way :

If $g\in W^0$ then $g=\sum_{i=1}^rc_ig_i.$ The hint says $\bigcap\limits_{i=1}^{r} N_{g_i}\subseteq N_g, \forall g\in W^0.$

So $$\alpha\in \bigcap\limits_{i=1}^{r} N_{g_i}\implies \alpha\in N_g, \forall g\in W^0\implies \alpha\in \bigcap_{g\in W^0}N_g\implies \alpha\in W$$

and we have the required inclusion.